# MySQL Displaying Product Descript and Price from two tables where Vendor is Null

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do my hw and I'm not sure why my code is displaying empty columns.

Instructions:
Write and run an SQL statement that displays description and price of products that were supplied by an unknown vendor (i.e., product vendor is not listed in the database). TIA!

My Code

```
SELECT P_DESCRIPT AS "Product Description", P_PRICE "Price"
FROM PRODUCT P, VENDOR V
WHERE P.V_CODE = V.V_CODE and V.V_CODE is null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use left join:

```
SELECT
    P_DESCRIPT AS "Product Description",
    P_PRICE "Price"
FROM PRODUCT P
LEFT JOIN VENDOR V
    ON P.V_CODE = V.V_CODE
WHERE V.V_CODE IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly